# C++, g++ compiling error function

Tags: c++, vector, g++

I can't make this work, it does not get compiled, I don't know where is the mistake. Can you help me?

I am creating a program that sorts a vector of "n" int numbers.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


void selection_sort(vector <int>& v){

  int last=v.size() -1;

  for(int i=0; i<last; ++i){

    int k = min(v, i, last);

    //Vector, position "i", and last vector position send to function


    swap(v[k],v[i]);//swap positions

  }


}



int min(const vector <int>& v, int left, int right){
```

And this is the error from the terminal:

```
g++ -o sortinglearn.x sortinglearn.cc
sortinglearn.cc: In function ‘void selection_sort(std::vector<int>&)’:
sortinglearn.cc:14:27: error: no matching function for call to   
‘min(std::vector<int>&, int&, int&)’
     int k = min(v, i, last);
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from sortinglearn.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:195:5: note: candidate:    
template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp& std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
     min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:195:5: note:   template argument   
deduction/substitution failed:
sortinglearn.cc:14:27: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter      
‘const _Tp’ (‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘int’)
     int k = min(v, i, last);
```

Comment: Please do not post links place your errors and code into the post

Comment: It baffles me that one would take the time to take a screenshot, redact it with some drawing software, upload it and embed it rather than just copy-pasting ten lines of text...

Comment: Also, the error is `using namespace std;`, which triggered a collision between your `::min` function and `std::min`. Remove that.

Comment: Protip: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @Quentin Ty mate, that is because i am new and i don't know to redact in this forum, i am learning XD. Is there any other way to fix it? Because i am only allowed to use `using namespace std;` in a exam.

Comment: @JonathanMee that is very interesting Jonathan i am reading it, but there is some stuff i am not allowed to use yet :(.

Comment: @Essence you are *forced* to use that damned directive in an *exam*? That's absolutely depressing... In any case, your function's full name is `::min`, so you could use that...

Comment: #undef min after the includes to remove the #define min(a,b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Quentin Ty mate! I have fixed it somehow, declaring the function `min` before `selection_sort`.